# Not using the argument in a method that requires an argument?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In this line of code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}
```

The author of the book did not use the `pickerView` argument, how come? I saw a lot of methods used like this, please explain.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use arguments if you don't need it.

In this example this is a delegate method and if you have just one UIPickerView in the view controller and you know that it will show just one component you simple return 1.

But if you would have lets say 2 UIPickerView and first will have 1 component and the second one lets say 3 you will have to see which UIPickerView is this method asking for:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    if (pickerView == pickerViewOne)
        return 1;
    else return 3;
}
```

Comment: is there any other case in which we dont have to use/define the parameters?

Comment: You should use the parameters just if you need them. If you have the method as above you don't have to use it. It's really depend on the project requirements.

Answer (score 8):

**It is not mandatory to use each of the parameters in a method.**

In the above method he must have only one pickerview and hence he doesn't want to check for which pickerview he needs to return 1. If he has multiple pickerviews then he can use the parameter to return some value conditionally.

*However if you enable Xcode to warn for unused parameter it will get warning for all unused parameter.*

[image]